# session not inserting in database syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, database

My form data:

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-control">

        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="order_product" class="form-control" ><?php
                            echo isset($_SESSION['item_name']) ? $_SESSION['item_name'] : $_SESSION['item_name'] = " ";

            ?></textarea>
         </div>

   <button type="submit" name="checkout" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Checkout</button>
  </form>
```

my place order function:

```
function place_order(){

if(isset($_POST['checkout'])) {

$ordered_product = escape_string($_POST['order_product']);

$query = query("INSERT INTO orders(order_product) VALUES($ordered_product)");
$last_id = last_id();
confirm($query);
redirect("../public/thank_you.php");
}
}
```

it shows error:

> QUERY FAILEDYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near '1-2, product 3-2)' at line 1

For 
product 1
product 3

Comment: Missing quotes in values

Comment: `....VALUES('$ordered_product')`

Answer (score 0):

You just need adding the quote for the query value.

```
$query = query("INSERT INTO orders(order_product) VALUES('$ordered_product')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$query = query("INSERT INTO orders(order_product) VALUES($ordered_product)");
```

With

```
$query = query("INSERT INTO orders(order_product) VALUES('$ordered_product')");
```